# How to get the current Google Docs document in a Google Workspace Add-on?

Tags: google-docs, google-workspace-add-ons

I'm creating a new Google Workspace Add-on using the [Cards API](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/reference/rpc/google.apps.card.v1#google.apps.card.v1.Card)

My runtime is Node.js. When the user opens my Add-on in Google Docs, the Add-on should know what the current document is.

I'm hoping to not use Apps Script.

I was expecting the request body that my app recieves include the document id. Right now the request body gets an empty 'docs' object.

This specification seems to indicate that the id should be in the body:
https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/guides/alternate-runtimes#docs-event

This is a resource I have used in development:
[https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/quickstart/alternate-runtimes](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/guides/alternate-runtimes#docs-event)